# TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder

Tags: solidity, remix

I am practicing my Solidity skills and while I did expect to get an error, I did not expect this error

> TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI
>   encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the
>   feature. function getArray() public view returns (string[]) {

This is my code in Remix:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Test {
    string[] public myArray;

    function Test() public {
        myArray.push("hola");
    }

    function getArray() public view returns (string[]) {
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

What gives here?

Is this because the standard ABI does not support dynamic nested arrays?

Comment: Are you sure you didn't cut off part of the error message? This is what I get: `TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.`

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, my apologies, I did not realize the error was that long until I extended it to take up almost the whole browser. I edited my post to reflect this.

Comment: Yeah, in this case, the error message is exactly what I would expect. `string[]` is not yet supported as a return value for a solidity function, but is planned to be supported sometime in the future, and they have started that implementation using the "experimental ABI Encoder V2". If this is a qualified answer, let me know and I will respond with similar details.

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi, yes its exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, please post your answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The error message you are seeing is a result of the fact that [Solidity does not yet support two levels of dynamic arrays](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/frequently-asked-questions.html#is-it-possible-to-return-an-array-of-strings-string-from-a-solidity-function), which a `string[]` would be:

> **Is it possible to return an array of strings (string[]) from a**
>   **Solidity function?**
>
> Not yet, as this requires two levels of dynamic arrays (string is a
>   dynamic array itself).

The error is telling you to add an additional line to the top of your code:

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
```

This feature came in [Solidity version 0.4.19](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/releases/tag/v0.4.19), which states:

> Code Generator: New ABI decoder which supports structs and **arbitrarily nested arrays** and checks input size (activate using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;`).

Note that in this case it does support nested arrays. I assume these features will eventually make their way into the production builds of Solidity, but it is not clear to me when. I tested, and your code does work when I add this additional `pragma` in remix.

Comment: Just a word of caution: on the 26th of March, the Solidity team [disclosed](https://blog.ethereum.org/2019/03/26/solidity-optimizer-and-abiencoderv2-bug/) a (small) vulnerability found in Solidity 0.5.6 and below when using `pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2`.

Answer (score 2):

Or just use

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
```

From Solidity v0.8.0 Breaking Changes https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/080-breaking-changes.html

> ABI coder v2 is activated by default.

So it is not experimental, but standard feature since `solc` v0.8.0